# What is meant by 'float' object is not callable?

Tags: python

I made another function similar to this one that worked fine, but for some reason I am getting an error on this one.

```
def minMaxScaler(data):
    s=sumList(data)
    me=meanList(data)
    min,max=minMaxList(data)   
    a=[(x-min(data))/(max(data))-(min(data)) for x in data]
    return a

b=minMaxScaler(data)
print(b)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [16], in <cell line: 48>()
 45     a=[((x-min(data))/(max(data))-(min(data))) for x in data]
 46     return a
---> 48 b=minMaxScaler(data)
 49 print(b)

 Input In [16], in minMaxScaler(data)
 43 me=meanList(data)
 44 min,max=minMaxList(data)   
---> 45 a=[((x-min(data))/(max(data))-(min(data))) for x in data]
 46 return a

Input In [16], in <listcomp>(.0)
 43 me=meanList(data)
 44 min,max=minMaxList(data)   
---> 45 a=[((x-min(data))/(max(data))-(min(data))) for x in data]
 46 return a

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: After you assigned a value to the name `min`, the built-in `min()` function is no longer available to you.  The same problem apples to `max`.  Choose different names for those variables.

Comment: On line 44 you're overriding the `min` and `max` names to be (floating point) numbers, which then can't be called on line 45